# Not able to start the IBM HTTP Server

Tags: apache, ibmhttpserver

We have taken the Images of the mount points from one existing IBM HTTP Server v8.5 and copied it to another Server. When we tried to start the server using ./apachectl start am not getting any error messages but no I couldn't find any httpd instance running.
When I tried to stop the server I got "httpd (pid 19422?) not running" message.
Changes have been made in httpd.conf by changing the server name.
Please let me know if this Image copying is possible?
If yes, please let me know where else should I have to make the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue, by granting the access to the particular file. It was due to different user who started the server on the parent server from where the Application was cloned.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you keep the path the same, and copy a stopped server, it should be fine.

If you change path, obviously you'll have to change all references to that path in the installation root.

If the server was running, when you copied it, you'll need to zap the PidFile (logs/httpd.pid by default). Usually this is recovered automatically.

Comment: copied the running server. In error logs i could find 
    "[error] (13)Permission denied: could not open transfer log file /ibm/HTTPServer/logs/access.log ".

Comment: Please advice in resolving this issue
    "you'll need to zap the PidFile (logs/httpd.pid by default)"

Comment: Remove the PidFile if you copied it from the other system.

Comment: Removed it, but not able to start the server. From Error log I found this
    "[error] (13)Permission denied: could not open transfer log file 
    /ibm/HTTPServer/logs/access.log.
    Unable to open logs
"

Comment: Solved this issue, by granting the access to the particular file. It was due to different user who started the server on the parent server from where the Application was cloned